# XML Schema - Allow multiple occurrences of some elements and require others

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

In a xml doc (which I **cannot** change) I have a structure like this:

```
<rootMeta> // all children can occur in any order
   <requiredExample1 value="someValue" /> // Should only be allowed to occur once. REQUIRED
   <nonRequiredExample2 value="someValue" /> // Should only be allowed to occur once. NOT REQUIRED
   <nonRequiredExample3 value="someValue" /> // All these are NOT REQUIRED but can occur many times.
   <nonRequiredExample3 value="someValue" />
   <nonRequiredExample3 value="someValue" />
</rootMeta>
```

I have tried "all" and "choice", but haven't gotten to a place where I can find a way to satisfy all the enforcements (first time at trying to build a schema). I tried to look for duplicate issues, but could only find solutions that would require me to alter the xml. My current iteration looks like this:

```
<xs:element name="rootMeta">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="requiredExample1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="nonRequiredExample2" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:maxLength value="200" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="nonRequiredExample3">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:maxLength value="200" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
          <xs:choice>
     <xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSD 1.1 you can allow any order, and define cardinality constraints, using xs:all.

In XSD 1.0 if you want to constrain the number of occurrences then you must also constrain the order.